# T-SQL Exclude scenarios where two or more records have two or more fields with the same value but one is different

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the table below:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE 
              (
                   Id INT,
                   Branch VARCHAR(50),
                   Color VARCHAR(50), 
                   Name VARCHAR(50),
                   Model VARCHAR(50)
               )

INSERT INTO @Data 
VALUES (1, 'London', 'Red', 'Mazda 3', '2015'), 
       (2, 'London', NULL, 'Mazda 3', '2015'),
       (3, 'London', 'Red', 'Mazda 2', '2014'),
       (4, 'London', 'Red', 'Fiesta', '2020'),
       (5, 'London', 'Yellow', 'Focus', '2010'),
       (6, 'London', NULL, 'Fiesta', '2020')
```

| Id | Branch | Color | Name | Model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | London | Red | Mazda 3 | 2015 |
| 2 | London | null | Mazda 3 | 2015 |
| 3 | London | Red | Mazda 2 | 2014 |
| 4 | London | Red | Fiesta | 2020 |
| 5 | London | Yellow | Focus | 2010 |
| 6 | London | null | Fiesta | 2020 |

I am aiming to exclude those records where the Branch, Name and Model are the same, but one of the rows has a specific Color value and the second row is null.

So, I would be only returning the id's below as the desired result, so Id's 1,2,4 and 6 should be excluded.:

| Id | Branch | Color | Name | Model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | London | Blue | Fiesta | 2020 |
| 5 | London | Yellow | Focus | 2010 |

I have tried the query below:

```
SELECT Data1.* 
FROM @Data Data1 
INNER JOIN @Data Data2 ON Data1.Branch = Data2.Branch 
                       AND Data1.Name = Data2.Name    
                       AND Data1.Model = Data2.Model     
                       AND Data1.Color = Data2.Color
```

But I still get the ones where the Color is not null as shown below.

| Id | Branch | Color | Name | Model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | London | Red | Mazda 3 | 2015 |
| 3 | London | Red | Mazda 2 | 2014 |
| 4 | London | Blue | Fiesta | 2020 |
| 5 | London | Yellow | Focus | 2010 |

Any guidance will be really appreciated !

Comment: why is id 6 excluded?

Comment: @Lamak because the join removed the null values.

Comment: sorry, I'm not understanding the criteria for excluding some rows. Then why should row 3 be excluded?. And though row 6 has a null value for color, it doesn't seem to fit your criteria of excluding `where the Branch, Name and Model are the same, but one of the rows has a specific Color value and the second row is null`

Comment: @Lamak apologies, instead of 3, it should have been id = 3, its been amended now.

Comment: @Kingsadrr Please check your data again. Sample data's 46h row doesn't match the result's 4th row.

Answer (score 0):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 DECLARE @Data TABLE 
               (
                    Id INT,
                    Branch VARCHAR(50),
                    Color VARCHAR(50), 
                    Name VARCHAR(50),
                    Model VARCHAR(50)
                )
 
 INSERT INTO @Data 
 VALUES (1, 'London', 'Red', 'Mazda 3', '2015'), 
        (2, 'London', NULL, 'Mazda 3', '2015'),
        (3, 'London', 'Red', 'Mazda 2', '2014'),
        (4, 'London', 'Red', 'Fiesta', '2020'),
        (5, 'London', 'Yellow', 'Focus', '2010'),
        (6, 'London', NULL, 'Fiesta', '2020')
```

Query:

```
 Select * from @Data Data0
 where not exists(
                    select * from @Data Data1 
                    inner join @Data Data2
                    on Data1.Branch=Data2.Branch and data1.Model=data2.Model and data1.id<>data2.Id
                    where Data1.color is not null
                    and Data2.color is null and (data0.id =data1.id or data0.id=data2.Id)
                )
```

Output:

| Id | Branch | Color | Name | Model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | London | Red | Mazda 2 | 2014 |
| 5 | London | Yellow | Focus | 2010 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c94449fce563bbffb7aea1edd2d8787)*

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but it appears you want to only list data where color is populated in each row if there is more than 1 row

### Filter using Duplicate Count vs Color Count

```
;WITH cte_Count AS (
SELECT ID
    ,Branch
    ,Name
    ,Model
    ,DupCnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Branch,Name,Model)
    ,ColorCnt = COUNT(Color) OVER (PARTITION BY Branch,Name,Model)
FROM @Data
)

SELECT *
FROM cte_Count
WHERE DupCnt = 1 /*Only 1 row for that combo of Branch-Name-Model*/
OR DupCnt = ColorCnt /*Color populated in each row*/
```

Comment: Window functions seem the best approach